# Is there a word for "to be physically removed from" a public place, involuntarily?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that means to be "physically removed from".

Imagine someone is being annoying in a public place, and refuses to leave when asked, so he is *physically removed from* the building. I'm looking for a single word.

Some of the ideas I had for words that may fit in are

**Removed**

> The beggar was removed from the restaurant.

I don't think this would work, because I want emphasis on that the beggar was taken and tossed out.

**Thrown**

> The beggar was thrown from the restaurant.

This one is alright, but I'm looking for something even *more* specific. Both of those words were what I could think of. I'm not too sure if there even is anything that fits better than "thrown", but I'm hoping there is an alternative.

Comment: ousted / ejected

Comment: What is your objection to "The beggar was *physically removed* from the restaurant"? All of the synonyms suggested in comments and answers seem more vague and less specific.

Comment: The question could use more context. The appropriate word would depend on the manner of removal, such as whether force, violence, or the law was involved.

Comment: I don't know if a single word will cut it, given people's affinity for figurative language. Getting "thrown" out is about as clear as it gets that you were physically thrown out, but this is normally used and interpreted figuratively.

Comment: If a window was utilized you could always say he was *defenestrated*.

Comment: @HotLicks I vaguely recall the suggestion of "defenestrate" being a semi-running joke here on ELU, but can't remember the other questions where it's come up.

Comment: Don't forget the most extreme form of being thrown out: Extraordinary Rendition.

Comment: It's not a single verb, but the adverb *bodily* is commonly used to make it absolutely clear that physical force was used to remove a person. It could be productively added to most of the good suggestions you've given and received (*bodily removed, ejected bodily*, etc.)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> #### Eject
>
> **verb** (used with object)
>
> 1. to drive or force out; expel, as from a place or position:
>      *The police ejected the hecklers from the meeting.*
>      Synonyms: *oust, remove, drive out, cast out, throw out.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/eject))

I think this word works best, since under the entry's example uses, is a usage of the word *eject* in the removal of someone from a hotel.

> Hotels can deny entry, gyms can deny access, and restaurants can eject you without consequence.
>
> [Anti-Gay Jim Crow Comes to Kansas](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/02/13/anti-gay-jim-crow-comes-to-kansas.html?source=dictionary)

Comment: I always think of *ejection* as a means of recovering coins from a vending machine, or the automatic process of shooting a pilot out of a crippled aircraft - *ejector seat*. These have given the word mechanical connotations, which in an earlier age would not have been there. So when anyone talks of *ejecting* someone from a restaurant I sort of imagine them flying up through a hole in the ceiling!

Comment: **From *The Big Lebowski*** ---

CHIEF: Mr. Treehorn tells us that he had to **eject** you from his garden party, that you were drunk and abusive.

THE DUDE: Jackie Treehorn treats objects like women, *man*. (I thought this makes a good supporting example, so appended.)

Answer (score 30):

**"expelled"**, **"forced out"** or **"driven out**" are all good fits.

> [**expel**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expel) - (verb) -  to eject or drive out with force

- The beggar **was expelled** from the restaurant.

> "Jesus sought out the blind beggar even after [the beggar was expelled](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22the+beggar+was+expelled%22&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0oNSstdPQAhWIgpAKHaZ5DloQ_AUIDygB) from his hometown."
>
> "X says she was [forced out](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=40&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi29fGat9PQAhXHIZAKHch1AR84HhAWCFowCQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkclr96fm.com%2Fkilkenny-resident-says-forced-home-severe-anti-social-behaviour%2F&usg=AFQjCNFu1oTQy6aVYYcjjwUk-XlwDcyv-g&bvm=bv.139782543,d.Y2I) of her home because of severe anti-social behaviour."

Comment: *"forced out"* is not the right term, unless you're talking about guerilla wars or land confiscations

Answer (score 21):

***Evicted***, I believe does it, and is probably the word I would use for someone removed against their will. It could include both an instance of physical force being used, or one in which the intruder was told in no uncertain terms to leave, but with a clear implication that their failure to do so would result either in the police being called, or their being physically removed.

In the UK there is no criminal law against trespass, and the only remedy the law provides to a land/property owner is the use of "reasonable force" to remove someone who has refused to go when asked.

However, one problem with *eviction* is that it is usually associated with legal eviction e.g. of tenants from a property they have legally occupied.

Comment: Signage TRESPASSERS WILL BE PROSECUTED should more accurately state, TRESPASSERS WILL BE SUED. Never seen any such sign in UK. With one or two exceptions under statutory or bylaws, trespass to land or property is not criminal offence but a civil tort actionable in County Courts, etc. The way for any property owner, tenant or lawful occupier to involve police & sanction of criminal law is to call 999 & report trespasser's presence, a situation that might lead to the common law criminal offence of breach of the peace should tenant exercise his right to use reasonable force to eject trespasser

Comment: @Peter Point. Trespassers guilty of no other crime or tort (e.g. causing damage or nuisance) can, in England and Wales, so far as I'm aware, be neither prosecuted nor sued civilly. It simply is not an offence. In practice many instances of trespassing involve something else which is an offence e.g. breaking and entering, causing distress or nuisance etc -(or the big catch-all - "behaviour liable to cause a breach of the peace") One important exception to this is trespassing on railway property. Otherwise any notice "Trespassers will be prosecuted" is meaningless. –

Comment: @PeterPoint I feel I ought to point out... you cannot just go and sit on someone's front porch all day and refuse to leave. Surely, there will be a point where you get arrested.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Yes. Although trespass is not an offence, it doesn't mean that you have a "right" to be on someone else's property. You are required to leave if asked to do so.If it was in close proximity to a residence (e.g. on the front porch) issues of *stalking* (which is nowadays an offence) or possibly *harassment*, or *loitering with intent*,  would come into play, and you could expect the police to take an interest. But if gypsies camp on your land, the police will generally not do anything about moving them on until you have obtained an eviction order from the court.

Comment: @WS2 that is absolute hogwash. If gypsies move into your property without permission then you do not need to evict them. They never purchased or were given the right to rent the land. Therefore, they were always trespassing, period.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Hogwash, old chap, would you mind telling me where you are located, which country's laws you are familiar with, and what your personal experience of gypsy encampments has been, please? Meanwhile you might like to read this [briefing material put out by a Borough Council concerning gypsy encampments](https://www.woking.gov.uk/planning/envhealthservice/control/unauthencampfaqs#does_the_council_or_police_have_a_duty_to_move_gypsiestravellers_when_they_are_camped_without_the_landowners_permission)

Comment: Signs reading "trespassers will be prosecuted" in the UK can be taken to mean, "trespassers will be prosecuted if and when they commit some offence, but I rather hoped that by phrasing that way I'd trick them into thinking they already were". But regardless of the legal situation, I don't think you call it "eviction" unless the person has taken up some form of "residence" however temporary. So you evict a squatter, but you eject a burglar. Merely standing in a restaurant shouting at the staff might not qualify for "eviction", but away from the law it's subjective.

Comment: I think it's true though, that in English law those travellers are trespassing as soon as they enter the property without permission. The surprise is that, even though they are trespassing, that doesn't mean they're committing any criminal offence. And although there's a civil tort even if they do no damage, in effect absent damage you're suing them for £0: all you get is a court judgement that they are indeed trespassing, which may embolden you to hire a group of toughs to evict them. Which is why the police can't do anything except under the circumstances listed in the advice WS2 links to.

Comment: @SteveJessop Trespassing isn't even a civil tort. However persistent trespassing, for which a person is repeatedly evicted, could be regarded as "nuisance", which is a tort and actionable.

Comment: @SteveJessop Re *evict* - the legal sense is undoubtedly the predominant one, however the word can be used in a less formal way - note OED sense 2c. *Hence transf. To eject (persons) forcibly from any position.1876   J. Weiss Wit, Humor, & Shakespeare i. 5   When a great freshet takes possession of a country and evicts the tenants of every hole, thicket, and burrow, there is an indiscriminate stampede of the animals.

1878   M. E. Herbert tr. J. A. von Hübner Ramble i. xii. 197   The new arrivals are the born antagonists of our enemies. They will evict them.*

Answer (score 16):

The beggar was [**booted**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boot) from the restaurant.

> *Verb* (informal) **4.** To forcibly eject.
>   *We need to boot those troublemakers as soon as possible*

The beggar was [**bounced**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bounce) from the restaurant.

> *Verb* **9.** (US, slang, dated) To eject violently, as from a room; to discharge unceremoniously, as from employment.

Comment: I like *booted*.  I will vote this up because the participant did provide links.  However, your answer will be better received if you copy the definition and include it in your answer.

Comment: This is why the person at the door is called a *bouncer* {they *bounce* people: "informal - eject (a troublemaker) forcibly from a nightclub or similar establishment."} : "a person employed by a nightclub or similar establishment to prevent troublemakers from entering or to eject them from the premises." –Google

Answer (score 12):

[***to be thrown out***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/throw_someone_out)

> to throw someone out: expel someone unceremoniously from a place, organization, or activity: ‘His wife had thrown him out.'  ‘Keane had been thrown out of the game by the umpire.'

*(Oxford)*

Your sentence:

> The beggar was **thrown out of** the restaurant.

*"I want emphasis on that the beggar was taken and tossed out."*  This expression emphasizes exactly that.

A variant of this is

***to be kicked out***

Answer (score 9):

> When used as a verb in American English, **eighty-six, eighty-sixed, 86, 86ed, or 86'd**, is slang for getting rid of something, ejecting someone, or refusing service

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/86_(term)

Answer (score 4):

I think [kicked out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/kick-out) would be a good expression to imply being removed forcefully

> 1 [TRANSITIVE] INFORMAL to force someone to leave a place or
>   organization kick someone out of something: Sonia’s been kicked out of
>   her house.

Answer (score 3):

> #### Banish
>
> **verb** (used with object)
>
> 1. to expel from or relegate to a country or place by authoritative decree; condemn to exile:
>      *He was banished to Devil's Island.*
> 2. to compel to depart; send, drive, or put away

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/banish?s=t))

This may be a slightly archaic choice of words but it is always nice to have variety.
By using the word *banish*, the removal of the person seems more permanent or more official.

You should also be aware  that banishment is usually *to* somewhere, for instance:

> He was **banished** out of the restaurant and *into* the cold of the night

Furthermore, *banished* implies that someone is removed not just temporarily but in a permanent way and it is generally from an entire area.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but the association with meaning #1 is so strong to me that it feels weird in the context the question asks about.

Comment: @Casey I agree, it doesn't fit fantastically but variety can't hurt. In the end, people come to this site for answers to *similar* questions to the ones on here. If this question helps out someone who is looking for a slightly more official way of saying this, then *banish* will help them.

Comment: *"banished"* implies not just removed once, and not just from one specific place, but permanently, and generally from an entire area.

Comment: People are banished from a kingdom, or a country, or a region, or a village. Not a restaurant, or City Hall.

Answer (score 1):

[Ousted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ousted): To eject someone from a position or place

[Disgorge](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disgorge): To discharge forcefully or as a result of force

[Send Packing](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/send+packing): To dismiss someone rudely ( *Two words but it conveys the same meaning as the above two*)

Answer (score 0):

[Manhandled](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manhandle)

could fit; from Collins:

> If someone is manhandled, they are physically held or pushed, for
>   example when they are being taken somewhere. [be V-ed] ⇒ Foreign
>   journalists were manhandled by armed police, and told to leave. [V n
>   prep/adv] ⇒ They manhandled the old man along the corridor. [Also V n]

**The beggar was manhandled out of the restaurant.**

Comment: Manhandled suggests a level of physicality that may not have occurred. The answer to this question largely depends on how forcible the eviction was.

Comment: In addition, you could be "manhandled" *in* the restaurant without being removed, so this is more a description of the *rough manner in which someone is treated during (event)*.

Answer (score -1):

To be [hoicked out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoick). From Merriam-Webster:

> :  to move or pull abruptly :  yank
>
> "I was hoicked out of my job"

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious - at least in AmE - is ***"bounced"***.

Hence, the term ***"bouncer"***, for the person designated to do the actual removing.

Answer (score -3):

I typically use "doored."

Edit note: The question itself asks for a word which means a specific thing. There is no possible, literate confusion whatsoever about what the meaning is, but since it is demanded: to remove from an establishment, using force, via a door (hence "doored").

Comment: This would probably be received better if you had citations or a link to an official definition supporting this usage... neologisms and nonce usages are generally not well-regarded here.

Comment: Six members of the community found your answer so poor they elected to delete it.  If you take issue with this community empowerment, please take your issue to our meta rather than adding distracting meta discussion to your answer here. If you take a look around our site a bit, you should get a stronger feeling for what sorts of answers are well received here.

Comment: @Hellion anthimeria